# My cycle's gears don't change properly

Tags: gears

At the rear wheel gear, the gear does not change from the 7th gear to the 6th gear when i change the gear in the handlebar once. But the next time i do it it changes. So, if the manual in the handlebar shows 5th gear,it is actually the 6th gear. What should i do?

Comment: There are many same questions in the forum. You can find even very detailed answers out there. Mainly it's because the gears aren't adjusted properly.

Comment: You adjust the derailer.  The symptoms you describe suggest that the cable tension needs adjustment -- something that every semi-serious cyclist should know how to adjust.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though your cable needs to be adjusted.

On the rear dérailleur there will be a barrel adjuster where the cable enters the mech. You can increase the cable tension by rotating the barrel adjuster anti-clockwise and loosen it by (you guessed it!) rotating it clockwise.

By getting the cable tension right you should be able to get more accurate shifting.

[Park Tools have a great guide to this on their website.](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/rear-derailleur-adjustment#article-section-6) You want section 6 on that page, which deals with indexing (the process of achieving accurate shifting).